# Local URL is added

Tags: php, iframe, echo, soundcloud

So, I'm trying to do this to echo all my Soundcloud tracks stored in my database (by URL). When the last echo is called, the URL is:

```
/End/public/https://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/121291880&auto_play=false&hide_related=false&show_comments=true&show_user=true&show_rep
```

I don't want the "/End/public/". Why is this happening? In the first echo (echo $musicArray[0]['url'];), the URL is correct (without /End/public). End is the project name, and public the public folder.

```
for($i = 0; $i < count($musicArray); $i++) {
echo $musicArray[0]['name'] . '<br>';
echo $musicArray[0]['url'];
echo '<iframe width="75%" height="150" scrolling="no" frameborder="yes" src=' . $musicArray[$i]['url'] . '&amp;auto_play=false&amp;hide_related=false&amp;show_comments=true&amp;show_user=true&amp;show_reposts=false&amp;visual=true"></iframe>';
}
```

Comment: What does your database looks like? Because a quick fix, without seeing your DB, would be the use of substr for your last loop. like substr($musicArray[$i]['url'], 12); and you got rid of /End/public/

Comment: http://imageshack.com/a/img910/411/GFxhoC.png
http://imageshack.com/a/img913/1614/ZtSRAE.png

Comment: I get the same thing with your quickfix. I'm so confused, since the URL is properly echoing in line 3.

Comment: I need to see what's up there, before your for loop. How do you fetch your $musicArray from your DB? Where does /End/public/ comes from? It's not supposed to be there at all if you are only getting data from your DB.

Comment: Yeah, that's the weird thing. In line 3 it's all echoing properly, just the URL, nothing else.

Comment: <?php

$db = new db();

$sql = "SELECT * FROM music";

$musicArray = Array();

$result = $db->query($sql);

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
 $musicArray[] = $row;
}

Comment: That's whats happening before.

Comment: And the db class is just a database class with simple methods as connection and query, nothing special.

Comment: I have a "define('ROOT', __DIR__);" in my bootstrap.php. Could that interfere in any way?

Comment: Well if you didn't put your root constant, it's not supposed to appear. Try to echo out only this : substr($musicArray[$i]['url'], 12); without the iframe, see what happen next.

Comment: I'll happily send you my project folder if you suggest any way to do it.

Comment: It works just fine.... I don't get this at all. I'm a beginner, but this is just confusing.

Comment: Mattias, do you have hangout, facebook or something so we can chat and see what's going on with your code, you only have 10 pts and can't chat at stackoverflow.

Comment: I think I sent you a Facebook message, check your spam folder.

Comment: It didn't work. Try Matthieu Boisjoli, I'm like on the beach with 3 other guys

Comment: That's the one I sent a message to. 'Other' folder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to add the whole src of your soundcloud inside your database instead of concatenating it. You are using API soundclound and perhaps something is interfering with your src.

Comment: "Oh, you are a genius matt! You solve my issue in only 1 step!"